# Where can i plug in my wrist strap and mat

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, repair

So I need to clean the fans of my laptop and i just wanna be on a safe side so i bought anti static wrist strap and mat.

CAN I put the anti statics wrist straps clip on the end of the laptops charger which is connected to a 3-pin which has a ground point, will that work?

Also I don't know know if the ground connection is still working or not, so is there any other place that I can use

Comment: Ignore the accepted answer on that duplicate. It's wrong, or at best misguided.